# odoo 14 - on windows : RTL rtlcss directions > solution here

Tags: odoo, arabic, odoo-14, rtlcss

1 - Install node js from official website : [www.nodejs.org](http://www.nodejs.org)

2 - open cmd and run : npm install -g rtlcss

3 - go to : C:\Users("User Here")\AppData\Roaming\npm  |  copy all files and dirs there

example : ("node_modules , rtlcss , rtlcss.cmd, rtlcss.ps1")

4 - create new dir in your odoo server dir and named as "thirdpartys" and Past all file in above there .

5 - now go to the file in the base modules named as "assetsbundle.py" | path : odoo/models/assetsbundle.py

6 - open file and go to the line (554):

if os.name == 'nt':
try:

- #rtlcss = misc.find_in_path('rtlcss.cmd')

- dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**))
- rtlcss = dir_path + "/../../../thirdpartys/rtlcss.cmd"

7 - save file and clear cache from webbrowser and run your server

8 - if you get any problem , try reboot your pc .

Good luck!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Install node js from official website : [www.nodejs.org](http://www.nodejs.org)

2 - open cmd and run : npm install -g rtlcss

3 - go to : C:\Users("User Here")\AppData\Roaming\npm  |  copy all files and dirs there

example : ("node_modules , rtlcss , rtlcss.cmd, rtlcss.ps1")

4 - create new dir in your odoo server dir and named as "thirdpartys" and Past all file in above there .

5 - now go to the file in the base modules named as "assetsbundle.py" | path : odoo/models/assetsbundle.py

6 - open file and go to the line (554):

if os.name == 'nt':
try:

- #rtlcss = misc.find_in_path('rtlcss.cmd')

- dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**))
- rtlcss = dir_path + "/../../../thirdpartys/rtlcss.cmd"

7 - save file and clear cache from webbrowser and run your server

8 - if you get any problem , try reboot your pc .

Good luck!